# Is there a way to login with facebook natively and redirect back to mobile site

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

If I have a responsive website that is mobile friendly and want to to authorize my user through logging in with facebook, is there a way to login with facebook natively and redirect back to my mobile site?

Edit: If I'm doing this as an iOS app, what's the best way to do connect a UIWebView to the native facebook login(iOS)?

Thanks SO.

Comment: If by _“login with facebook natively”_ you mean via the Facebook App – no, because there is no connection between the native app and the browser that could facilitate this. You will have to implement the normal login flow in your mobile site.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do that either.